# How to use file_get_contents or cURL after logging in

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I need to download the source of a page after logging in manually. I'll explain:

After logging in manually, I can open any other link on the site and I am logged in.
If instead I use file_get_contents, it returns me the page without login (**in the same browser!**).
Is it solvable in php?

Form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same session. For example, with curl:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


?>
```

If you close the session, you close the 'login'. 
If you don't close the session, you can reuse the handler $ch to use in other pages:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
    curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

This way, since you are using the same session, you still have the login. And then close de handler:

```
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: This doesn’t necessarily need to be done using the same cURL handle though; cURL has the ability to store cookies in a file and read them back from there to send back to the server later (it just needs to be configured via the according options.)

Comment: yes you are right. I just use this method in my last project and it works very well. Sometimes I have to do both, use the same handler and use the cookie save on file. It depends always the site and the login architecture used by the developers.

Comment: It doesn't work!
`$url="mylink";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_exec($ch);
echo $ch;`

Comment: you probably don't want to echo the handler, but the response of the exec. $content  = curl_exec($ch); echo $content

Comment: if this didn't work, look for other curl options, like CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, CURLOPT_HEADER, etc ...

Comment: it's the same! :( I don't know how cURL work properly!

Comment: what do you receive, printing the content?

Comment: and what do you want to see?

Comment: the code that is shown after login. The page is the same site/index.php

Comment: for that you need a new Curl option. CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , this will follow the location of the pages, whenever appens a redirect. This can or can't work depending on the site, and the developers architecture. You can check all the options here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php. By my experience with cURL, when it does not work , 90% of the times, it's just a missing option or a new different set of options.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); doesn't work!